# AmCharts - lines of different color

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, charts, amcharts

I need to have lines between the bullets on the same graph to be a diffrent color, i.e. if line is raising (going from bullet of smaller value to greater value) it needs to be green, if line is going down it needs to be red.

I have found one option of the AmChart graphs which is graph.negativeLineColor. This has similar concept but it change the color if line is higher or below 0 which is not what we need.

Or is there any other charts tool that could do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 3.0 amCharts introduced a feature where you can change graph color at any point:
http://www.amcharts.com/javascript-charts/line-chart-with-changing-color/

You need to set colors in your data and then specify lineColorField for your graph.

Comment: Thanks , It was helpful.

Comment: can't you set the colors in the theme? for example, set an Array of 20 colors, and if you happen to have 20 or less lines, they will be colored according to the theme-specified colors?